# Sound won't play twice

Tags: java, audio

I have been working for days to try to fix my program. It plays a song once successfully, but it cannot re-play the song.

Weirdly enough, when attempting to create an short, self-contained example, I found that the same code can play a song, stop, then play a different song, but will not play the same song twice in a row. Given that on my app I don't know if the user will chose the same song again, so the stream *must* be closed and re-opened.

Here is an example demonstrating broken code(will not play song again):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test{
    static Clip musicplayer;
    static AudioInputStream currentSong;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            musicplayer = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new test().getClass().getResource("test.wav")); 
            playMusic(ais);
            System.out.println("Playing Music");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            stopMusic();
            System.out.println("Stopping Music");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            playMusic(ais);
            System.out.println("Playing Music for the Second time");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Finished Program");
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static void playMusic(AudioInputStream music){
         if(music == null)
             return;

         if(currentSong != null){
             if(currentSong.equals(music))
                 return;
         }

         currentSong = music;

         try {  
               musicplayer.setFramePosition(0);
               musicplayer.stop();
               musicplayer.open(currentSong);    
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        musicplayer.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public static void stopMusic(){
        musicplayer.close();            
    }
}
```

If I add another AudioInputStream in, and play that as my second song, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in this piece of code

current song is never reset so if you try to play the same stream twice it will just abort.

```
...
     if(currentSong != null){
         if(currentSong.equals(music))
             return;
     }

...
```

To clear it.

```
public static void stopMusic(){
    musicplayer.close();            
    currentSong = null;  // we do not have a current song anymore.
}
```

The other problem is that you are not reseting your input stream.
The simplest way is to just reload it. Streams are not array that you can give to something and it will magically start at the beginning. Anything accessing a Stream can only get whatever is next, if you give something a Stream where the next bit is the end then nothing will happen.

```
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new test().getClass().getResource("test.wav")); 
    playMusic(ais);

    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new test().getClass().getResource("test.wav")); 
    playMusic(ais);
```

one thing to be aware of is that AudioInputStream does not implement equals so

```
 AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new test().getClass().getResource("test.wav")).equals( AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new test().getClass().getResource("test.wav")))
```

will evaluate to false.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work. The currentSong field is so that it will only play when a different song is chosen, or when the song is stopped. you can check the method by printing each varible to see where the thread gets to.

Comment: The real solution was to work around it by reloading the sound every  time it wanted to be played... :( I will accept your answer as setting the currentSong to null may have helped somewhat with the solution

Comment: BevynQ answer is correct not for the a "workaround" you think you made. You do not update `currentSong` or `music`. They are strictly the same object.

Comment: @user2097804 I have added some details.